# Merge two functions, str_replace?

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to replace som characters when importing data from a feed. I'm not sure how I can merge two functions into one to make an url correct.

Tried to place one function inside another, but that didn't work.

https://www.xxxxxx.se/brand/[my_custom_function2([my_custom_function3({brand[1]})])]/

How can I combine following two into one?

```
<?php
function my_custom_function2($string) {
    $string = str_replace (" ", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
function my_custom_function3($string) {
    $string = str_replace ("AÃ©ryne", "Aeryn", $string);
    return $string;
}
?>
```

Thanks!

PS. I have hundreds of brands and some is two words. For example "Billi Bi". That is the reason I need the first function.

Comment: Placing a function in a function should work. Otherwise, copy the str_replace from func3 to func 2 before the return line.

Comment: Notice that the parameters are `mixed`, you can also use `str_replace(array(" ", "AÃ©ryne"), array("-", "Aeryn"), $string);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace several characters using single call by passing array in [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
str_replace (array("AÃ©ryne"," "), array("Aeryn","-"), $string);
```

Wrap above in single function you don't need n str_replace() calls to replace n characters

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function combine_functions($string){
   $string = my_custom_function2($string);
   $string = my_custom_function3($string);
   return $string;
}
function my_custom_function2($string) {
    $string = str_replace (" ", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
function my_custom_function3($string) {
    $string = str_replace ("AÃ©ryne", "Aeryn", $string);
    return $string;
}
?>
```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

Why not to call functions this way
$result = my_custom_function2(my_custom_function3(brand[1]));

$url = "https://www.xxxxxx.se/brand/{$result}/";